# Find the length of an arraylist when the arraylist is located in a different Class

Tags: java, file, arraylist, menu

So I'm trying to find out the length of an arraylist, but the arraylist is being stored in a different class, how am I able to fix this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StarberksInterface
{


public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    store = new Store();
    String str, sName1, sName2, name;
    char c;
    int n=0;
    sName1 = "Callahan";
    sName2 = "Lambton";


    //This is the main menu that will be displayed first.
    System.out.println("       MAIN MENU FOR MANAGEMENT SYSTEM");
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.println("1. CHOOSE STORE");
    System.out.println("2. DISPLAY STORES");
    System.out.println("3. LOAD STORE VIA FILE");
    System.out.println("4. SAVE STORE TO FILE ");
    System.out.println("5. EXIT PROGRAM");
    System.out.println("===============================================");

    while(n!=5)// Exits the program when 4 is pressed
        {
            System.out.print("\n Please enter option 1-4 to continue...: ");
            n = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
            // Reads user input and takes them to selected code.
            if (n>5||n<1)
            {
                System.out.print("Invalid input, please try again...");
                continue;
            }
            if (n==1)// Takes to option 1 or sub menu
            {
                str="y";

                while(str.equals("y")||str.equals("Y"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter a store name [Callahan or Lambton] ");
                    name = console.next();
                    if (sName1.equals(name)|| sName2.equals(name))
                    {
                        StarberksInterface.subMenu();
                        continue;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("There is no store under this name. Please try again.");
                    }

                }

            }
            if (n==2)// Gathers products in stores and displays the number of products
            {
                System.out.println(" Store data is being displayed.");
                System.out.println("===============================");
                System.out.println("Store: Callahan");
                System.out.println("       Number of products: "+store.size());

            }
        }
}
```

so that code above is for where I want the length to be displayed.

this code is where the arraylist is populated.

```
    public static Product product;
public static Store store;
// Where the user inputs the data for the item
public static void addItem ()
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    product = new Product();// initiates the product and store to being empty.


    String desc, id, str="";
    double price = 0, sUpPrice = 0, unitCost = 0, inventoryCost = 0;
    int stock = 0, demand = 0;


        System.out.print("Please enter product description between 3 to 10 characters...: ");
        desc = console.next();
        desc = desc.toLowerCase();
        product.setName(desc);


        if ((desc.length() < 3 || desc.length() > 10))
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make description between 3 to 10 characters.\n");
            System.out.println("Try again with different input. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            StarberksInterface.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter price in $ : ");
        price = console.nextDouble();
        product.setPrice(price);

        if (price < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            StarberksInterface.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter set up price. $ : ");
        sUpPrice = console.nextDouble();
        product.setsUpPrice(sUpPrice);

        if (sUpPrice < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            StarberksInterface.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter unit- cost. $ : ");
        unitCost = console.nextDouble();
        product.setunitCost(unitCost);

        if (unitCost < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            StarberksInterface.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter the inventory cost. $ : ");
        inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
        product.setinvCost(inventoryCost);

        if (inventoryCost < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            StarberksInterface.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter the amount in stock : ");
        stock = console.nextInt();
        product.setstock(stock);

        if (stock < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            StarberksInterface.addItem();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter the demand of the product : ");
        demand = console.nextInt();
        product.setdRate(demand);

        if (demand < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
            System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            StarberksInterface.addItem();
        }

        System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
        System.out.print(desc +" Product was added successfully ");
        System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
        // stores the item in the array


        //Checks to see if item is already in the list
        /*while (product != null)
        {
            if (product.equals(store.getProduct(desc)))
            {
                System.out.println(desc +" is already a product.");
                System.out.println("Input for data will restart");
                StarberksInterface.addItem();
            }
        }*/

        store.add(product);
    }
```

and finally the following code is in a file called Store.java, this is where the arraylist is.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Store{
// stores the product information in an array list
//allows for numerous products and each can be called in the Starberks Interface
public ArrayList <Product> ProductList = new ArrayList<Product> ();

public Store()
{

}

public void add(Product product)
{   
    // Adds the product and all details entered by user to the list.        
    ProductList.add(product);
}

public Product getProduct(String prodName) {
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < ProductList.size(); i++) {
            //searches through list of products to find a specific name entered in
            // from the Starberks Interface
        if (ProductList.get(i).getName().equals(prodName)) {
            return ProductList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
 }

 }
```

Comment: `ArrayList.size()` .... thats how you find it.  add to your store class... `public int getNumberOfProducts() { return ProductList.size(); }`

Comment: Is your Store class is a different project or in the same project?

Comment: I'm guessing you want the size of the ArrayList to be returned where you typed `store.size()`? Either replace `store.size()` with `store.ProductList.size()` or write a method in the `Store` class that returns 'ProductList.size()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a getter method inside your Store class to access the size of list

```
/*your list reference has a size() method that you can call to get the size of list in store class and can access that via a getter */
public int getProductListSize(){

return ProductList.size();
}
```

Also in your any other class where you have store class reference you can access it easily like

```
store. getProductListSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not another **file**, it's another **class**. To access a member of a class, you need to access it via an object of that class. For example, in your code, you can access the arraylist by using `new Store().ProductList`. Although this would be empty at first, but after you added some products into it, this would have some objects.

As you are using `store.size()`, I think you need a method `size()` declared in your `Store` class, which would return the size of your arraylist.

By the way, there are some general issues in your code 
1. Public variables/objects in class
2. getProduct() is returning null, which is hiding it's true purpose.

Comment: sorry the main bit of the code is in a file called inv.java the arraylist in a file called store.java

Comment: That is fine Raznish, that's how we separate out our classes. We generally keep each public class in it's own file. Still we don't call them file, we call them classes because that's how they are represented in Java. I hope you have some basic knowledge of Java and not using someone's code.